# Fantasy Novel on woman needing to have a child?

Tags: story-identification, novel

Trying to remember a book about a woman who I think was a princess or at least nobility. She was supposed to have a kid because she was the only one capable of having kids since she was born, and there was a mass 'natural' killing of all other children. The main male character was sent to infiltrate(?) and ends up getting with her. It's a trilogy, and this specific book is the second in the series, but I can't remember the author or book name. The main Male character comes from another country(?) where they are going through a drought or had just gotten over one. I think the main female character's name was Tori, but I'm not completely positive. For some reason, I have a scene in my head where she is specifically wearing a 'white shift' and standing in a doorway or in a hall.

Comment: Possibly something by Traci Harding? Her main protagonist is Tory, but I've only read the first so don't recognise your plot at all.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could say anything about when the book was published, or at least when you read it. Also what other fantasy elements were in it: magic, dragons, etc.

Comment: its been awhile since I have read the book, but there was little to no mystical creatures that I can remember. I don't know the publication date, but I read it in about 2014-15. There must have been some kind of magic because the mass killing was done through the curse or prophecy of an oracle or something. I think the main male character was a orphan in a war, who was 'adopted' or at least brought in by a family that was in charge of another nation or country